# Cannot upload a file when Angular code is compiled

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

I'm trying to upload file to this BE Spring code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<StringResponseDTO> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("id") Integer merchantId) throws Exception {
        ..............
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new StringResponseDTO("test"));
    }
```

Returned object:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonTypeName("response")
public class StringResponseDTO {

    private Map<String, String> errors;

    public StringResponseDTO(String redirect) {
        super();
    }

    public StringResponseDTO(Map<String, String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(Map<String, String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

Angular code:

```
imports(file: any, id: number) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    return this.http.post(environment.api.urls.merchants.uploadLogo, formData, {
      params: { id: id.toString() }
    }).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

When I run the code locally it's working fine. I get http code 200 and response `{"response":{}}`. But when I compile the code and run it on Apache I get error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

Full error: https://pastebin.com/cMKbGsZN

After debugging I get this into response content: https://pastebin.com/hiCypy4T

Can you give me some advice how to fix this?

Is there some other solution to implement file upload? Probably I need to return only status OK?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` means that your server returns (probably) as HTML (or XML) file instead of JSON. Open the dev tools to inspect the response.

Comment: Yes - https://pastebin.com/hiCypy4T

Comment: So you're either hitting the wrong endpoint, or your server wrongly returns `index.html` for that. Don't just look at the response in the devtools, what's the URL?